# Reason behind Kashi Yatra in Indian Wedding

Tags: rituals, marriage, culture, customs, kashi

In Indian marriages, especially the South Indian Weddings, I have noticed the ritual of Kashi Yatra. This ritual involves  persuading the groom to accept the girl for marriage and enter Grihastasramam. What is the true significance of this ritual ? In Present day, There is no groom going to Kashi,then why this procedure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the boy comes of age for Marriage,after the **Vratham, Kankana Dharanam and Nandi**, the Boy goes to [Kasi](https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/hindu-wedding-rituals-vratham-kankana-nandi-kasi-yatra-detail/)(Benares, Varanasi ,the Holy City of The Hindus, to meditate on the Brahman, The Reality.(Symbolically)

The bride’s father intervenes and requests the Bridegroom not to undertake the trip,become a Grihastha as Grihathaasrama is the fundamental Stage of Dharma or the Path of Righteousness, and offers his daughter in Marriage , promising that she will be his soul mate in performing the Vediac rituals that would guarantee spiritual enlightenment.
As there are few places(Manu smriti and Mahabaratha) where it is said you can attain the divine
by becoming a Grihastha no need to leave everyone and do penance. 
Staying in Grihathaasrama you can follow the Dharma and please God.

I hope this would help.

[image]

**Edited: Translation of the content in attached image to English.**

Before the time of Adishankaracharya and after him many people have left Samsara or Grihathaasrama in search of true Knowledge realizing that the Samsara is fundamental cause of Miseries. Sanyasa is not the mainstream part of Indian Culture. For developement of Vedic Character/Culture(my interpretation of word Charitra in this context)in Indian community Ramayana and Mahabharta played vital role. In these epics no character is Sanyasi.

Maharishi Veda Vyasa in Mahabharata told his son Shukadeva 'Grihasthatvesha dharmanaam sarvesham mulamucyate', i.e. "This Grihastasharmaa is the root(most important/prominent again no better interpretation of word Mula) of all Dharama" MB ShantiParva 234.6. Manusmriti(6.89) says 'Grihastha Uchyate Shreshtaha", Grihasthashrama is best amongst all ashrama.

Comment: Mano ,can u translate that highlighted texts in the image to english.?Many users may not know how to read Hindi.

Comment: The interpretation of highlighted text Mano please add this to your answer, if you think this translation is sensible/consistent with the original hindi text. Before the time of Adishankaracharya and after him many people have left Samsara or Girhastashrama in search of true Knowledge realizing that the Samsara is fundamental cause of Misries.

Sanyasa is not the mainstream part of Indian Culture. For developement of Vedic Character/Culture(my interpretation of word Charitra in this context)in Indian community Ramayana and Mahabharta played vital role. In these epics no character is Sanyasi.

Comment: @Rickross Continued.... Maharishi Veda Vyasa in Mahabharata told his son Shukadeva 'Grihasthatvesha dharmanaam sarvesham mulamucyate', i.e. 
"This Grihastasharmaa is the root(most important/prominent again no better interpretation of word Mula) of all Dharama" MB ShantiParva 234.6. 

Manusmriti(6.89) says 'Grihastha Uchyate Shreshtaha", Grihasthashrama is best amongst all ashrama.

Comment: @Mano I understand the procedure of Kashi Yatra. But, in the present day, nobody goes to Kashi in search Brahman, after their education. Then why this practice ? Is it just a meaningless ritual.

Comment: @Rickross Sorry I had been away from my system so dint do what was asked however Yogi has nicely translated.

Comment: In some communities instead of the father, the brother of the bride goes to the groom and requests to marry his sister .

Comment: @Ganesh Many Rituals are created and followed upon time and necessity However from this one we can derive a positive point i.e Making the person understand how holy the Grihathaasrama  is. Nowadays it is important to make people aware so they dont take things granted it can be any decision pertaining to life.

Comment: @mano Its ok,no need to be sorry.